# How to prevent Ubuntu 16.04.2 from upgrading kernel version to 4.10.x and xserver to 1.19.x

Tags: kernel, updates

How can I prevent Ubuntu 16.04.2 from upgrading kernel version to 4.10.x and xserver to 1.19.x?

Uncheck “unsupported updates (xenial-backports)” Ubuntu Software & Updates setting, running below commands can avoid Ubuntu16.04.2 kernel upgrade to 4.10

```
apt update
```

But this won't prevent Ubuntu from kernel upgrade to 4.10 and xserver to 1.19 by running

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
```

Are there other better ways of handling this?

[image: Ubuntu updates setting]

Also, what will happen when 16.04.3 is released?

Comment: You can uninstall HWE meta packages and use the 4.4 kernel. `xenial-backports` are not related.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the [`HWE` guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack).

There is [another good link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

The 4.8 kernel has a limited support in Ubuntu. If you want to have a "stable" kernel that won't be updated to other major versions, you can install Ubuntu 16.04.1 that has the 4.4 kernel. It will be supported till the 16.04 EoL in 2021.

Another option is to install the 4.4 kernel by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

then remove all 4.8 (HWE) kernels and you are done.

The same thing is with X.org.

The package is `xserver-xorg`. If you install it, other meta packages (xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04) will be automatically removed.